# Unknown margin of li elements

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a navbar with css but the `li` elements have 2px `margin` to left and right, even when I use `margin: 0`, and I have to use `margin: 0px -2px` to "fix" it

Here is the original code snippet

```css
ul,
li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
nav{
    background:#333;
}
nav ul{
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
nav ul li a{
  background: green;
    color:#fff;
    padding:15px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try floating your li elements to the left. The display inline-block property doesn't rest the elements directly next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `display: inline-block` the element creates a space because it gets inline, so you need to fix that space,

There are [**few ways**](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)  to fix that space:

- Remove the spaces
- Remove the spaces using html comments `<!-- -->`
- Negative margin (personally I don't advise it to use)
- Skip the closing tag, which HTML5 allows (again personally I don't advise it to use)
- Set the `font-size` to zero
- Set them `float`
- Use flexbox

For this code, you can use `font-size:0` in parent `ul` because you are setting already `font-size` in child `a`

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  background: #333;
}
nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  font-size:0
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li a {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">home2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">home3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">home4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: `display:inline-block` does not create a gap by itself, it rather forces elements to be placed inline and so spaces separating such elements become significant.

Comment: @c-smile exactly, I'm aware of that, I know that is the element who gets inline and then inline level elements have those spaces

Comment: @c-smile I updated the explanation to be more truthfully. Thanks for the heads up.